# av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer youtube.

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, live-streaming

i want to live stream to youtube with ffmpeg but i take error " av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer". i send stream with FMLE its works nice.

```
ffmpeg -re -i /mnt/windows/21.mpg -r 30 -s 854x480 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -f mpegts "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/hasanbagcaci.3s3v-pkwx-g64b-5zgz" -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)"
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to send a livestream to YouTube:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /mnt/windows/21.mpg -r 30 -s 854x480 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/hasanbagcaci.3s3v-pkwx-g64b-5zgz"
```